# do-release-upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: do-release-upgrade

We have some servers still on 16.04LTS. I want to get them to 18.04LTS. But with 20.04 out, do-release-upgrade offers only that new release. We won't go to 20.04 until the .1 version comes out for stability reasons.

Is there a way to get do-release-upgrade to offer to install 18.04LTS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Please show us the output of `grep Prompt /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`